# AT-ST at the Battle of Hoth in the original version of Episode V?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, battle-of-hoth

Are there any AT-STs at the Battle of Hoth in the original version of *The Empire Strikes Back*?

A friend of mine says there is an AT-ST in the Battle of Hoth in the movie, but after re-watching it I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I definitely remember seeing one, but I'm not sure if that was in the original version of the movie.

Comment: i just watched it on youtube, it claims its the unedited version and i didn't see one, but i could have missed it.

Comment: Looks like AT-ST models were made for the original filming. See [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Scout_Transport#Behind_the_scenes) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328101504/http://www.starwars.com/databank/vehicle/atst/index.html). But that doesn't confirm that a shot with an AT-ST was included in the original version of the movie.

Comment: my friend says they show one either getting dropped off, or that an AT AT drops an AT ST out.

Comment: I remember seeing it walking, not being deployed.

Comment: I distinctly remember exactly one shot of one lone AT-ST walking in the background in the original version of ESB. I'll upload a shot of it if no one else has by the time I can get my hands on my old VHS tape.

Comment: There's one at 5.46 in this version http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WASr5-mS238

Comment: @Richard That's exactly what I remembered. I'm just not 100% certain it's in the original version.

Comment: @Richard thats what he was looking for, now to determine if its the original or not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just reviewed the battle from my copy of the original theatrical cut.<sup>x</sup>

One AT-ST is clearly visible walking behind an AT-AT at 30:25.

[image: First AT-ST at Hoth]

Another AT-ST can be seen at 33:20, just as Luke sabotages one of the AT-ATs.

[image: Second AT-ST at Hoth]

These are the only two seen throughout the entire battle.

---

<sup>x</sup> These screenshots are from the "Bonus" DVD of *The Empire Strikes Back*, from the 2008 Star Wars Trilogy (Widescreen Theatrical Edition) boxed set.

Comment: Beat me to it, as I thought someone would. +1

Comment: Interesting and relevant; http://i.stack.imgur.com/UWU5B.png

Comment: The fun thing about this shot is that it just looks so fake and composited that one would be forgiven for assuming that it was special edition material.  But yet it's not.