# Why are tracked vehicles rarely used/seen?

Tags: star-wars

Throughout star wars, tracked military vehicles have not been prominent, but other types have- for example, the Clone Turbo tank was a *wheeled* vehicle that was used in rough terrain. My understanding is that tracked vehicles are often used by armies to scale rough, boggy and uneven terrain that wheeled vehicles would find hard to travel across.
I am aware that there have been tracked vehicles that feature in *Star Wars*, such as the [Combat Assault Tank](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TX-225_GAVw_%22Occupier%22_combat_assault_tank), used by the Imperial Army, and the [MLC-3 light tank](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MLC-3_light_tank), used by the Rebel Alliance. I am also aware that hover vehicles and armored vehicles with legs are also popular, but they perform are meant to go where neither vehicles with [caterpillar tracks](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76087/what-is-the-benefit-of-an-at-at-walker-over-a-conventional-tank) or wheels are meant to go.**So why are tracked vehicles not featured more prominently in Star Wars?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treaded vehicles aren't seen because [Repulsorlift](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Repulsorlift) Technology is cheap, efficient, and prolific in the Universe. This tech takes up all the environments where tracked vehicles would theoretically be the most useful on.

Prolific:
It's used in varying capacities on nearly every world we are introduced to, Speeders and speeder bikes, used as landing engines for spacecraft, even Imperial Star Destroyers can use it to hover in Atmo.

Cheap:
The widespread use even on backwater worlds like Tatooine means that this tech is cheap enough (and energy efficient enough) to be used whenever one needs a vehicle that can go on all terrains.

Efficient:
You don't need to bring certain vehicles to invade certain planets (except submarines for obvious reasons) when  you can bring one tank/transport that hovers over the environment and go on them all.

**Anytime you need an all-terrain vehicle you would be better off using Repulsors**

The better question might be why are All-Terrain vehicles are walkers when you have a much better All-Terrain tech widely available. Possibly it's not as reliable as we're led to believe. Why you would risk taking an ISD into atmo on only repulsors that aren't as reliable as landing gear like we see on Acclamators would be an interesting case study I guess.

I get what you are saying too, tanks with treads would seem to be more stable/useful than the walkers, but they are used less I think because of coolness factor. I'm also not sure on the breakdown rates of walker leg vs turbo tank wheel vs tank tread vs laat/lambda repulsor.

We do see a number of hover tanks in the star wars uni, most of which are no longer Disney canon.
The droids used MTTs and AATs on the world of Naboo in the swamps where I assume most tanks or wheeled vehicles would get stuck:
[image: MTT crush trees on Naboo]

The [Imperial Assault Tank](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_assault_tank) is present in the comics

The [T2B tank](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T2-B_Repulsor_Tank) is noted for it's speed and versatility, although it also says one of the reasons it lacks heavy weapons is because of the repulsors.

And the [TX-225 GAVr "Occupier"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TX-225_GAVr_%22Occupier%22_combat_assault_tank) is used on Lothal for speed and All-Terrain capabilities in conjuction with walkers on the show Star Wars Rebels.

Answer (score 1):

The most notable tracked vehicle in the saga is, naturally, the Sandcrawler - the transports the Jawas of Tatooine use in their scavenging pursuits. As we see them in both the Prequels as well as the Original Trilogy, we can surmise that repulsorlift technology for land-based vehicles is relatively new during the end of the Galactic Republic era, but the lack of basically any other kinds of tracked vehicles shows that repulsorlift tech is stable and economical enough for mass use.